# Make [abseiling] a synonym of [rappelling], not [abseil]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Currently, people are voting to make [abseil](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abseil) a synonym of [rappelling](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rappelling). This is file, but it doesn't appear that anyone has suggested a synonym of [abseiling](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abseiling) into [rappelling](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rappelling).

I have not got enough rep to do this, so could someone propose [abseiling](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abseiling) be a synonym of [rappelling](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rappelling)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, why not.

Answer (score 2):

I tried but I can't:

[image]

Comment: Ahh okay then. Doesn't really matter which way round I guess!